# Finding column-number of a value without knowing the row-number it is located in

Tags: excel

I am trying to find columnnumber of an value without know the row-number.
I am sure it is an easy answer but for now I am stuck with an long IFERROR-formula that checks every first 15 rows:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH("Prices";Prisliste!$A$2:$L$2;0);IFERROR(MATCH("Prices";Prisliste!$A$3:$L$3;0);"-----and so forth..
```

Someone have a better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AGGREGATE:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A$2:$L$16)/($A$2:$L$16 ="Prices"),1)
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked examplary!

Comment: Please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.